# Panel duplicated on multiple monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I install clean Ubuntu 12.04, and i have problem with multiple monitor configuration. I have 3 monitors on 2 video card. In 10.04 LTS a have 3 top, and bottom panel and everything work fine. In 12.04 when i restart or logout/login every panels configured last time move into first(base) monitor. On other two monitors a new panels are created. On two others monitors background also don't show.

I have installed the drivers for my card and they work fine.

Comment: did you install proprietary drivers for the graphics card?

Comment: yes. Drivers are fine.

Answer (score 0):

look in display:
    at button of window:
        launcher placment

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754606